# kinect in Ubuntu-VMware workstation question

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The command runs in Ubuntu-VMware workstation,and I have installed the driver of openni_kinect in ubuntu.But the results is 'no devices connected',so how can I do next?
Thank you very much!

*ocean@ubuntu:~$ rosrun openni_camera openni_node
[ INFO] [1333005176.028312616]: [/openni_camera] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1333005177.034397683]: [/openni_camera] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1333005178.042672712]: [/openni_camera] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1333005179.049414569]: [/openni_camera] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30747/kinect-in-ubuntu-vmware-workstation-question/) by [Ocean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2058/ocean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running VMware Player 4 with a virtual machine of Ubuntu 11.10 and have installed openkinect libraries. I can see my Kinect and the freenect-glview demo works and displays the RGB depth image and a full color video image side by side. It is tricky to get the Ubuntu to "see" the kinect device however, as Windows 7 grabs it first when it is plugged in. But there is a pulldown in Player ... VirtualMachine-> RemovableDevices-> where the "microsoft xbox nui motor" shows up. If you select it, there is a field that says "Connect(Disconnect from host)". If I select that, it disconnects from the "host" which is Windows 7 and "Connects" to it with Ubuntu. After a few seconds, two other devices show up in this list: "microsoft xbox nui camera" and "microsoft xbox nui audio". Go through the same process to Connect to both of those as well. Once they are all connected, they should show up as little USB drive icons at the bottom of VMware Player as well. After that, the freenect-glview works (at least for me). I am on a 64 bit Dell with 32 bit virtual Ubuntu.
BTW, I tried this same process running Ubuntu in Virtual Box, and never got it to see the Kinect.

---

Originally posted by [Shonn E](https://answers.ros.org/users/2078/shonn-e/) with karma: 26 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-03-29**:
Poster's point about VirtualBox is spot on, in my experience: VirtualBox has terrible virtualized USB support.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Kinect doesn't work in a VMWare guest (at least, it doesn't work when using the openni drivers).

This is widely-reported and reproducible.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-03-30**:
(and very irritating, I might add)